# Iterate through numpy array testing multiple elements efficiently

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code which iterates through 2d numpy array named "m". It works extremely slow. How can I transform this code using numpy functions so that I avoid using the for loops?

```
pairs = []
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        if(i >= j):
            continue
        if(m[i][j] + m[j][i] >= 0.75):
            pairs.append([i, j, m[i][j] + m[j][i]])
```

Comment: What the dimensions of this array?

Comment: about 5000x5000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use vectorised approach using NumPy. The idea is:

- First initialize a matrix `m` and then create `m+m.T` which is equivalent to `m[i][j] + m[j][i]` where `m.T` is the matrix transpose and call it `summ`
- [`np.triu`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html)`(summ)` returns the upper triangular part of the matrix (This is equivalent to ignoring the lower part by using `continue` in your code). This avoids explicit `if(i >= j):` in your code. Here you have to use `k=1` to exclude the diagonal elements. By default, `k=0` which includes the diagonal elements as well.
- Then you get the indices of points using [`np.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) where the sum `m+m.T` is greater than equal to 0.75
- Then you store those indices and the corresponding values in a list for later processing/printing purposes.

---

**Verifiable example** (using a small 3x3 random dataset)

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
m = np.random.rand(3,3)
summ = m + m.T

index = np.argwhere(np.triu(summ, k=1)>=0.75)

pairs = [(x,y, summ[x,y]) for x,y in index]
print (pairs)
# # [(0, 1, 1.2600725493693163), (0, 2, 1.0403505873343364), (1, 2, 1.537667113848736)]
```

**Further performance improvement**

I just worked out an even faster approach to generate the final `pairs` list avoiding explicit for loops as

```
pairs = list(zip(index[:, 0], index[:, 1], summ[index[:,0], index[:,1]]))
```

Comment: Suggest you add `np.random.seed(0)` up at the top and rerun to give repeatable results.

Comment: Decreased my program execution time from 55 sec to 1.5 sec. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @nota: I edited slightly to include `k=1` because you don't want the diagonal elements

Comment: @nota: To get more speed up check my edit using `zip`

Answer (score 5):

One way to optimize your code is to avoid comparison `if (i >= j)`. To traverse only the lower triangle of the array without that comparison, you have to make the inner loop start with the value of `i` of the outermost loop. That way, you avoid `size x size` `if` comparisons.

```
import numpy as np
size = 5000
m = np.random.rand(size, size)
pairs = []


for i in range(size):
    for j in range(i , size):

        if(m[i][j] + m[j][i] >= 0.75):
            pairs.append([i, j, m[i][j] + m[j][i]])
```

Comment: It's better to define first size and then use it in `m = np.random.rand(size, size)`